# I need an example of the use of Euler's Theorem for polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I need an example of the use of this theorem for $\mathbb Z / 3$ if possible.

`Let  ∈ [],   a finite field and: ()={  ∈ []: 0 ≤  ≤  and (,)=1} So, for all  ∈ [] with (,)=1, we have: ^(())≡ 1 ( )`

For instance, apply this to $x^3 + 2x + 1$

PS: Consider   as the degree of a polynomial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is a bit un-imaginative, but we can perform pseudo-primality tests:

*Claim:* $m=x^3+x+1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

*Proof:* If not, then $\varphi(m)=\left|\mathbb{Z}_3\right|^{\deg m}-1=26$. Thus by Euler's theorem, $x^{26}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. However by explicit division with remainder, we find that
$$x^{26}\bmod m=x^2\ne 1$$
Thus $m$ is not irreducible. Indeed, $m=(x-1)(x^2+x-1)$.

Comment: Primality testing is, indeed, a nice application of this. In retrospect, the factorization you gave shows (by CRT) that
$$\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/(m)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_3[x]/(x-1)\oplus\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+x-1).$$
Which, in turn tells us that $\phi(m)=(3^1-1)(3^2-1)=16$. And we can check that $x^{16}\equiv1\pmod{m}$. Actually $x^8$ will already do, because $8=\operatorname{lcm}(3^1-1,3^2-1)$.

Comment: More to the point, when testing for irreducibility in the ring $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ we can forget the "pseudo" part! Undoubtedly you know that $x^{p^n}-x$ is the product of all irreducible monics with degree $d\mid n$. Together with a test of being square-free, it is easy to build a *deterministic* irreducibility test for a polynomial of degree $n$ out of this. Check that no monomial $x^{p^d-1}, d\mid n, d<n$, gives the correct remainder but $x^{p^n-1}$ does. $\gcd(p^a-1,p^b-1)=p^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$ and all :-)